# How to Get the Authorization header from wcf request interceptor

Tags: wcf

I need to authenticate every request to wcf services

```
 public class AuthenticationInterceptor : RequestInterceptor
    {
        public AuthenticationInterceptor() : base(false)
        {
        }

        public override void ProcessRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
          //How to access Request Header (Authorization header) from here?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the headers from the `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message`, so try

```
var message = requestContext.RequestMessage;
var request = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)message.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];

string authorization = request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];
```

Comment: I didn't have quite the same setup so needed this to get it working: var requestContext = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext;